# How to find and return bottom-most(Deepest Node) node of a binary tree? binary search tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a `binary tree` with the only condition that there is a single node in the deepest level.  The nodes in the tree have the parent property (as well as left, right, data)

Is it possible to determine what the node at the deepest level is in better than `O(N`)?
What if the tree is a `binary search tree (right->data > parent->data, left->data < parent->data)`instead of a binary tree?

I can get there using a breadth-first approach which gets the job done in O(N) for both the binary tree and binary search tree but wanted to know if there was a better approach.

Comment: the notion of depth of a node is orthogonal to the value it holds. Unless your tree structure keeps track of it somehow there's no way you can do it faster than O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with a balanced tree you'll have to check every sub-tree to find the deepest node, like:

```
struct RESULT{
    Node *node;
    int level;
};
RESULT getDeepest( Node *root ){
    if( root == NULL ){
        RESULT result = {NULL, 0};
        return result;
    }
    RESULT lResult = getDeepest( root->left );
    RESULT rResult = getDeepest( root->right );
    RESULT result = lResult.level < rResult.level ? rResult : lResult;
    ++ result.level;
    if( result.node == NULL )
        result.node = root;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

no way of doing better than `O(n)`.

Consider a tree when all nodes have only left child - you'll need to scan all the nodes in order to get to the deepest one.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say O(n) not log(n)...  Is there any way to do this in better than N time?

Comment: I don't think you can get better than `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public Node deepestNode(Node root, int level){
        int deepestLevel=0;
        Node deepestNode=null;
        if(root==null){
            return null;
        }
        deepestNode(root.left,level++);
        if(level>deepestLevel){
            deepestLevel=level;``
            deepestNode =root;
        }
        deepestNode(root.right,level++);//not sure of increment
        return deepestNode;
    }
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, it needs an explanation to be an answer.